# Why does Files.readAllBytes first read with a bufsize of 1?

Tags: java, linux, kernel, driver

I am writing a simple Linux USB character driver allowing to read a short string from the device node it creates.

It works fine but I noticed a difference between reading from the device node with `cat` and reading from a Java program with [Files.readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-).

**Reading with `cat`**, a buffer with size 131072 is passed in at the first call to the `file_operations.read` function and the 5 bytes string is copied:

```
kernel: [46863.186331] usbtherm: Device was opened
kernel: [46863.186407] usbtherm: buffer: 131072, read: 5, offset: 5
kernel: [46863.186444] usbtherm: done, returning 0
kernel: [46863.186481] usbtherm: Device was released
```

**Reading with `Files.readAllBytes`**, a buffer with size 1 is passed in at the first call, and then a buffer with size 8191 is passed and the remaining 4 bytes are copied:

```
kernel: [51442.728879] usbtherm: Device was opened
kernel: [51442.729032] usbtherm: buffer: 1, read: 1, offset: 1
kernel: [51442.729102] usbtherm: buffer: 8191, read: 4, offset: 5
kernel: [51442.729140] usbtherm: done, returning 0
kernel: [51442.729158] usbtherm: Device was released
```

The `file_operations.read` function (including the debugging `printk`'s) is:

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer, size_t length,
        loff_t *offset)
{
    int err = 0;
    size_t msg_len = 0;
    size_t len_read = 0;

    msg_len = strlen(message);

    if (*offset >= msg_len)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "usbtherm: done, returning 0\n");
        return 0;
    }

    len_read = msg_len - *offset;
    if (len_read > length)
    {
        len_read = length;
    }

    err = copy_to_user(buffer, message + *offset, len_read);
    if (err)
    {
        err = -EFAULT;
        goto error;
    }

    *offset += len_read;

    printk(KERN_INFO "usbtherm: buffer: %ld, read: %ld, offset: %lld\n", 
            length, len_read, *offset);

    return len_read;

error:
    return err;
}
```

The string read in both cases is identical, so I suppose it is okay, I am just wondering why the different behaviour?

Comment: Can you see what `size()` returns for your device node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GNU `cat`**

In the source of [`cat`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c#n687),

```
      insize = io_blksize (stat_buf);
```

you can see that the buffer's size is determined by coreutils' `io_bliksize()`, which has a rather [interesting comment](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ioblksize.h#L23-L24) in this regard,

> /* As of May 2014, 128KiB is determined to be the minimium blksize
>   to best minimize system call overhead.

So that'd explain the results with `cat`, since 128KiB is 131072 bytes and the GNUrus decided that's the best way to minimize system call overhead.

**Files.readAllBytes**

Is a bit more difficult to grasp, at least for a simple soul like me. The [source of `readAllBytes`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#3147)

```
public static byte[] readAllBytes(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(path);
         InputStream in = Channels.newInputStream(sbc)) {
        long size = sbc.size();
        if (size > (long)MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
            throw new OutOfMemoryError("Required array size too large");

        return read(in, (int)size);
    }
}
```

shows it's simply calling `read(InputStream, initialSize)` where the initial size is determined by the size of the byte channel.  The `size()` method also has an interesting comment,

> The size of files that are not isRegularFile() files is implementation
>   specific and therefore unspecified.

Finally, [`read(InputStream, initialSize)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#3094) calls `InputStream.read(byteArray, offset, length)` to do the reading (comments in source are from the original  source and are confusing things since `capacity - nread = 0`, so the first time the while loop is reached, it does *not* read to EOF):

```
private static byte[] read(InputStream source, int initialSize)
        throws IOException {
    int capacity = initialSize;
    byte[] buf = new byte[capacity];
    int nread = 0;
    int n;
    for (;;) {
        // read to EOF which may read more or less than initialSize (eg: file
        // is truncated while we are reading)
        while ((n = source.read(buf, nread, capacity - nread)) > 0)
            nread += n;

        // if last call to source.read() returned -1, we are done
        // otherwise, try to read one more byte; if that failed we're done too
        if (n < 0 || (n = source.read()) < 0)
            break;

        // one more byte was read; need to allocate a larger buffer
        if (capacity <= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - capacity) {
            capacity = Math.max(capacity << 1, BUFFER_SIZE);
        } else {
            if (capacity == MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
                throw new OutOfMemoryError("Required array size too large");
            capacity = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        buf = Arrays.copyOf(buf, capacity);
        buf[nread++] = (byte)n;
    }
    return (capacity == nread) ? buf : Arrays.copyOf(buf, nread);
}
```

The declaration of `BUFFER_SIZE` for [`Files`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#2748)

```
    // buffer size used for reading and writing
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
```

Documentation/source of `InputStream.read(byteArray, offset, length)` contains a relevant comment,

> If length is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned;

Since `size()` returns 0 bytes for your device node, here's what happens in `read(InputStream source, int initialSize)`:

In the first round of the `for (;;)` loop:

- `capacity=0` and `nread=0`.  So the `source.read` in the `while ((n =
  source.read(buf, nread, capacity - nread)) > 0)` reads 0 bytes into `buf` and returns 0: the condition of the `while` loop is false, all it does is `n = 0` as a side effect of the condition.
- Since `n = 0`, `source.read()` in `if (n < 0 || (n = source.read()) < 0) break;` reads 1 byte, the expression evaluates to `false`: our `for` loop  doesn't exit. This results in your "**buffer: 1, read: 1, offset: 1**"
- the `capacity` of the buffer is set to `BUFFER_SIZE`, the single byte that was read is put into `buf[0]`, and `nread` is incremented.

The second round of the `for (;;)` loop

- thus has `capacity=8192` and `nread=1`, which makes `while ((n = source.read(buf, nread, capacity - nread)) > 0) nread += n;` read 8191 bytes from offset 1 until `source.read` returns -1: EOF!  Which happens after reading the remaining 4 bytes. This results in your "**buffer: 8191, read: 4, offset: 5**".
- Since now `n = -1`, the expression in `if (n < 0 || (n = source.read()) < 0) break;` short-circuits on the `n < 0`, which makes our `for` loop exit without reading any more bytes.

Finally, the method returns `Arrays.copyOf(buf, nread)`: A copy of that part of the buffer where it put the read bytes.

Comment: Hmm, the `read()` method you provide actually reads byte by byte, there is no `it tries to read the rest of the bytes.` in it. Special processing of the first byte is used for differenciate situations, whether *any byte* has been read before error/exception. It affects on returning value/exception, as required by method's specification.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Agreed, that's a better explanation for the processing of the first byte.  I'm also confused about where `size()` gets it "unspecified" value from, perhaps that's the root of it.

Comment: `size()` returns 0 for the device node, while it returns the actual size of a regular file like i.e. `ls -l`.

Comment: @TorstenRömer   `size()` of 0 makes `read(inputStream, initialSize)` call the `read(byte b[], int off, int len)` method three times, one reads 0 bytes, one reads 1 byte, one reads `BUFFER_SIZE-1` bytes.  So we're on to something :) I'll remove the last part of the answer and edit the full source of `read(inputStream, initialSize)` into it first.

Comment: Nice :-) So, since `size()` for a non-regular file can return 0, the method first checks if it is possible to read from it anyway by reading just one byte, and then reads the rest if that succeeds?

Comment: @TorstenRömer  Yes.  In short, it reads 0 bytes, then 1 byte to see if there's anything to read, then `BUFFER_SIZE-1` bytes until EOF.  I gotta see how I edit the answer to explain that in a readable fashion :P